# How to stop Android AlarmManager when there is a manual system time change?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Here is an extended example of the problem. It is 1:30AM. Alarm is set for later today, at 10AM. I change my phones time to 1159PM yesterday. Alarm Manager instantly triggers, at the wrong time.

How do I stop the AlarmManager from ringing if the time is in the past?

If however, I change the time forward, nothing happens.

I do not want this to happen with my app, as it does not happen with other Alarm apps. Is there a way to make sure that the Alarm manager only rings at the exact minute it is set (if not skip it)?

Here is my Alarm Manager code.

```
        Calendar alarmCal = closestAlarm.toCalendar();

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, ActiveAlarmService.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("alarm", closest);

        pendingAlarm = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmService.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingAlarm);
```

I have tried using a BroadcasetReceiver to catch the Time/Date change events, but there is too much lag between the broadcast, and the AlarmManager firing because it is set in the past.

Comment: You can always manually check the time.  Setting any other type of timer is unlinkely to be a good idea-  if you're setting the timer far into the future then you need to use an alarm to be persistent if your service or activity is closed.

Comment: @GabeSechan, well I thought I could do that. For me to check the time manually, I would need to do so in the service it launches, and that feels like it uses a ton of unnecessary code and processing power on something so trivial. And I agree about the timer, that was a bad idea. I have updated my question slightly.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, (I haven't seen this behavior, but I haven't really ever tried either).  I do have a warning for you-  exact is hard to get in Android.  In KitKat, a lot of am functions changed to explicitly not trigger exactly on time to prevent wakeups.  In Marshamallow they added a 2nd layer of this (there's now set, setExact, setInexact, setAndAllowWhileIdle, and setExactAndAllowWhileIdle).  Beware of expecting any alarm to be exact.  set is actually exact on preKitKat, inexact on post based on your target SDK.

Comment: @GabeSechan, Much obliged. Thanks for the tip too, though I don't really need it to be exact, I really only need it to ring the minute it is set to.

Comment: I'm really surprised by why it fired immediately after you changed the time to 11:59 pm while your alarm is set to 10 am.

Comment: @Dummy Well it fired because it thinks the Alarm is in the past, switching the time changed the date back one.

Comment: You can listen for this intent http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED

Comment: @Dummy, Unfortunately I have tried that. There's too much lag between the broadcast and the AlarmManager. I have found a solution however, I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It feels odd, but it is solid.

Here is what I was using originally.

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
    alarmTimeCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingAlarmIntent);
```

This was the solution.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimeCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingAlarmIntent);
```

You will have to manage and cancel this AlarmManager as if it was the first method. If you forget, your alarm will ring when it should not.