# Canceling alarms from AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am working on application which is get the alarm time from database every 2 AM and then at the specified time the activity shows up, my app works fine, but when I manually change the data/time of the device, previous alarms are triggered and I should prevent to this to happens.

Here is my `PendingIntent`:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);  
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(G.context, _id, i,
                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Which each `_id` is unique and when I make a receiver for date changed event before my alarm cancel method fired previous alarms go off!

Can some body help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mote.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);     alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);`

Answer (score 0):

For cancel the alarm:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mote.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

**Edit**

Well you can look for the answer and modify as per your requirements:

[How to stop Android AlarmManager when there is a manual system time change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932969/how-to-stop-android-alarmmanager-when-there-is-a-manual-system-time-change)

[AlarmManager: how to schedule a daily alarm and deal with time changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421616/alarmmanager-how-to-schedule-a-daily-alarm-and-deal-with-time-changes)

Comment: hi please note that i want to cancel the alarm when system date/time is changed!! before this code is running the alarm is fired!!

Comment: @SeyedMassoudMotallebi Check for edit. and tell me if the links provided are useful.

Comment: Intent intent1 = new Intent(G.context, DailyAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(G.context, G.dateTimesetAlarm.getDayOfYear(), intent1,0 );
        mAlarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
but there is no help

Comment: @SeyedMassoudMotallebi have you solved your problem? or i need to check with your code?

Comment: hi not yet the problem still exist when i changed the time manually it's fired!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(G.context, DailyAlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(G.context,
     G.dateTimesetAlarm.getDayOfYear(), intent1, 0);
 mAlarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
 pendingIntent.cancel();
```